# Como travar versão de projeto no symfony

Tags: symfony-2

Estou com uma versão 2.6 no symfony e gostaria de travar meu projeto nela para não correr o risco de dar um update e começar a dar bugs.

Alguém sabe o comando para fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No composer você vai definir da seguinte forma:

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
```

Fazendo assim, quando você usar o comando `composer update`, só vai ser atualizadas as correções de bugs específicos dessa versão.